# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: javascript, node.js

what I'm trying to do here is a post-search method that takes an input from the search textbox in the .ejs file and renders searchresults page but whenever I try it gives me an error     `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`

```
let allPlaces = ['annapurna', 'bali', 'inca', 'paris', 'rome', 'santorini'];
    app.post('/search', function (req, res) {
        let z = req.body.search;
        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017", function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // let db = client.db('myDB');
            // let collection = db.collection('myCollection');
            let searchresult = [];
    
            for (let j = 0; j < allPlaces.length; j++) {
    
                if (allPlaces[j].includes(z.toLowerCase())) {
                    searchresult.push(allPlaces[j]);
    
                }
            }
            if (searchresult.length === 0) {
                alert("Can't find what you are looking for");
            }
    
            res.render('searchresults', {place: searchresult});
    
        });
    });
```

Comment: req.body.search is not a string, did you use the `express.use(express.json())` middleware? are you sure the client is sending the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `let z = req.body.search;` is always available,

<s>default it to a string as follows:</s>

```js
let z = req.body.search ?? '';
```

`req.body.search` is not a string, did you use the `express.use(express.json())` middleware? Are you sure the client is sending the string?.
Make sure you're doing that.
And in case there wasn't a search string, <s>you should make a default for it, an empty string is enough "".</s>

Or you can have an if statement to detect:

```js
if(typeof req.body.search !== "string") throw new Error("please privde a search term")
```

Comment: about the empty string part: `if (allPlaces[j].includes("")) {` is equivalent to `if (true) {`

Comment: @Thomas, ah yes, .

Comment: I will double-check that.

Comment: `app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));`   it's added and the same happens I even added the check line of typeof and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Here's the .ejs code of the search                                                                          
`<form method="POST" action='/search' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="Search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"><button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button></form>`

Comment: it's "search" with small letter, not "Search" change the `name` attribute in your ejs file